# Classic form to XPAGES

Tags: xpages

I have a classic lotus notes form with 1800 fields and 7 tab,

1. Will the performance improvement if i split the form in 7 different form and then bind to the xpages 
   or
2. if i directly bind the form to the xpages will there be any performance impact?

thanks

Comment: Why are there 1800 fields on one form? Would it be an idea to redesign the form to see if you can move some fields to other forms etc ?

Comment: this is an existing design and MAX document size is only 34 KB, i would like to know if we move the form design to XPAGES and keep the existing design will there be any performance impact ?

Comment: I think the correct question is why you even need 1,800 fields to begin with? It isn't like:  line_item_1 ... line_item_999 ? If so you would be better off recoding it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "try that with your RDBMS" type of situation.
Splitting forms will not help you, XPages doesn't care too much about how many data sources are used if the number of bindings is high (and you have a ratio of still > 200 for many forms) --- and you actually don't bind to a form, you bind to a document. The form is only a "design time convenience".

Making some wild guesses I would presume that a lot of the fields are repeating fields (like LineItem_1 LineItem_2 LineItem_3 ) instead of multi-value fields.

Moving forward you need to make a basic choice:

Is your data format fixed since all views, reports, import/export routines etc. rely on them .or. can you refactor the data model (based on your question I would presume the former).

If it is fixed I would look to encapsulate the document into a managed bean that provides collections of data for the repeating sets of fields and repeat controls to show the number of entries you actually need (The classic way would be to have different hide whens in every cell of the table hosting the fields). This way you have much less bindings to look after.

A very basic idea how to have a dynamic table can be found in [Excercise 23](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-23) of the [IBM XPages tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/tutorial-intro-to-xpages.htm)

Disclaimer: [Tim Clark](http://www.tc-soft.com/wordpress/?page_id=2) and I wrote that.

You also might consider using only that parts of the document the specific user needs that moment.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. i will try to use the repeat controls

Comment: It helps to accept an answer --- and there is only one e in my name. The second should be an a.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, As of my concern, You have a form with seven tabs and 1800 fields. But it is too complex. But however we split a form into seven, each form will have 260 fields. now also code will become complex.

But my suggestion is that you can dynamically change the binding data in xpages. If you feel very complex to redesign the form then you follow the above idea. Otherwise change the design and make a nice look-up in xpages.